# One CPU in a 32-core system is getting to 100% usage and hurting performance

Tags: sql-server-2005, performance

I am experiencing a problem with one server. It has 32 cores and seems to be well-configured in all aspects (memory, hard disk drives...). Performance Dashboard is not showing blocks or deadlocks and no waiting tasks. All queries seem to be performing well.

From time to time (every 5-6 minutes) one of the cores gets up to 100% utilization and the system's performance slows down. It lasts for some seconds.

What should I check to know what is causing this misbehaviour?

It is a SQL Server 2005 standard edition with Service Packs installed.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Do you have a machine with 32 cores for SQL Server Standard? Don't remember about 2005, but 2008 R2 was limited to 4 processors (no limit in cores) and 2012 was limited to 16 cores. Are you using all cores for SQL Server or is there any other application server on that machine?

Comment: Is there an increase in storage activity during those peak times as well?

Comment: @Marian Yes, 32 cores, all dedicated to SQL Server.

Comment: @JonSeigel Do you refer to I/O activity? Disk activity seems to be ok and no contention has been detected. I suspected initially of tempdb, but is perfectly configured and running smoothly. I suppose some query is making a full table scan on a very high table, but performance dashboard is not complaining about any specific query. The system seems to be quite well dimensioned. I have even installed idera and the only warning I get is "Page Life Expectancy" under 300, which again leads us to page faults and bad performing queries.

Comment: Yes; I was trying to see if the peaks were correlated with database checkpoints. From your response, that doesn't sound like the case. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

What *process* is using that CPU? You need to monitor the [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms804621.aspx) object and figure out which *instance* (ie.process) is driving CPU up. Also is important to distinguish between privileged (kernel) vs. user time. Also important to see if is not [`Interrupt Time`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms804036.aspx) by any chance.

The purpose of the exercise it o establish if is a hardware resource interrupt driving the CPU (I've seen this with some many network cards for instance), a user process (and which process). *If* you established that is SQL Server process then you can switch investigation to SQL Server specific means, at which moment it turns into SQL performance investigation well suited to [Waits and Queues](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966413.aspx) methodology. But if the problem is outside SQL then perhaps the best methodology to deploy is [USE](http://dtrace.org/blogs/brendan/2012/02/29/the-use-method/). And [Kernrate](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24853) is your friend.

Comment: Thank You. I will proceed as you say and will come back with answers to your questions.

Comment: We ha ve determined the following: When this CPU gets to 100%, the number of page faults per second also rises for SQL Server and, thus, for the whole system. This makes the System processor time to go up. So, it is the system which makes the CPU go to 100%, but it is because SQL is increasing its page faults. But, why? I don't know. SQL Server is using >64GB RAM Memory from a total of 96GB in the system. Memory use is limited for SQL to 88GB. It seems that there is no query causing this page faults as well.

Comment: If you're seeing page faults for SQL server, then something else is forcing SQL to page out memory.  Try to identify what else would be using memory on the machine and/or decrease the memory allocated SQL, Also, you might consider setting lock pages in memory for sql server, though I wouldn't go that route until you figure out what else if using memory.

Comment: How high is the faults/sec? Hundreds, thousands? Is it [soft faults or hard faults](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781216(v=ws.10).aspx)? I assume is a 64 bit instance (at 88GB gotta be...). Any active antivirus?

Comment: @StrayCatDBA The server is dedicated to SQL Server and has more than 8GB available for the system.

Comment: @RemusRusanu thousands. I will check whether they are soft or hard. Thanks.

Comment: Can you capture [`Process(*)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms804621.aspx), [`Processor(*)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms804036.aspx), [`Memory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms804008.aspx), [`SQL Server: Buffer Manager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173929(v=sql.80).aspx), [`SQL Server: Memory Manager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173937(v=sql.80).aspx) for about 5 minutes (cover both 'normal' and 'high' CPU), at 5 seconds interval, save the .PDH and make it available for us to look at?

Comment: Hello @RemusRusanu They are soft page faults. Anyway, I will try to capture the trace you are proposing.

Comment: I have the file, but the server is in German, and so are the counters. Do You want me still to make it available? I just can tell you that during performance "crises", both Page faults / second and Transition faults / second for the memory countes rise up to about 5.500 for about a minute and then go down again. Any other counter seems to be OK.

Comment: Upload it non the less. A number of contributors here speak Swiss, and translating the counter names is not a problem even for non-speakers.

Comment: Performance problems 08:03:58 – 08:04:28 and 08:06:30 – 08:06:45 (solid green and blue lines are up to the middle at those moments). [link to the file](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-ZxBq268Sn5X0t5WGUtR0ZxZVk/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: You included `Process(_Total)`, not `Process(*)`

Comment: Hello @RemusRusanu You can add those indicators. They are in the trace. I am checking which processes are generating the Page Faults.

Comment: Sry, did not check *that*. You can see that during the problem periods the counters that have spikes are: `Prozessorzeit(%)` for **System** (not for SQL, nor for any other process) and is 100% private CPU time and *many* process' `Seitentfehler/s` (page faults), with worst offender being `sqlservr`, but also significant activity with several `SQLdm*` processes. Also `SqlWb`, `taskmgr`, `explorer`, `lsass` and several `srvhost` show page faults. My suspition would be a  DM Management Services collector task that runs every 5 mins.

Comment: File Closed. It was hyperthreading! http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kevin_kline/archive/2007/08/18/the-perils-of-hyperthreading-for-sql-server.aspx Thanks for your help @RemusRusanu